# Is it possible to show a character value in the APNS badge?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, badge

Has anyone done this?  I would like to show a "!" instead of a number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`applicationBadgeNumber` on `UIApplication` is defined as such:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger applicationIconBadgeNumber;
```

No strings, only integers.

Comment: And apparently no negatives as I needed to show a golf score value.

Answer (score 0):

It accepts integer as badge number so you cant show "!" as badge ..